# While loops and Increment Operator confusion

Tags: loops, while-loop, operators, increment

While working on a practice problem on the Practice-It! website, I ran into this problem:

```
public static void mystery(int x) {
int y = 1;
int z = 0;
while (2 * y <= x) {
    y = y * 2;
    z++;
}
System.out.println(y + " " + z);
```

}

The x integers given were:

```
mystery(1)
mystery(6)
mystery(19)
mystery(39)
mystery(74)
```

The only answer I got was mystery 1, which was 1 0. The z++ is really confusing me
For the others, I have tried several answers, with none working. The way I am trying to approach this problem is( using the mystery(6) integer):
since (2 * (1) <= (6)) 
{ y = (1) * 2; y = 2
for mystery(6) i put 2( the y value) and 5 as the z value( because I THOUGHT that the z value will increase for each +1 from the x value. The that was wrong, so I tried 2 1, because I thought that maybe z would only increase by one, which was also wrong.

I apologize for such a messy post, but I don't have much time to post this( not a due date, but just a bunch of stuff unrelated to this that need to be done) Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the y values changes by this amount
y = y * 2;
every time through the loop

so you get: 
y-value | time through loop

1 | 0

2 | 1

4 | 2

8 | 3

etc